# Python 3 - Read CSV from URL after testing for header

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to generate records from a csv retrieved from a given url in Python 3.

Given `urlopen` returns a bytes-mode file object but `csv.DictReader` expects text-mode file objects, I've had to wrap the `urlopen` file object in a `TextIOWrapper` (with a utf-8 decoding). Now, unfortunately I'm stuck between two undesirable options:

1) `TextIOWrapper` doesn't support `seek`, so I can't reset the `csv_file` generator after checking for a header with `Sniffer`.

2) If I don't `seek` back to 0, I truncate the first 18 records.

How do I modify the below code so that it can both check for headers and yield all records off of one `urlopen` call?

**What have I tried?**

Reading the URL twice: once to check for headers, a second time to generate the csv records. This seems suboptimal.

Code that skips the first 18 records below. Uncomment line 12 to generate the `seek` error.

```
import csv
import io
import urllib.request


def read_url_csv(url, fieldnames=None, transform=None):
    if transform is None:
        transform = lambda x, filename, fieldnames: x
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as csv_binary:
        csv_file = io.TextIOWrapper(csv_binary, "utf-8")
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csv_file.read(1024))
        #csv_file.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if has_header and fieldnames is not None:  #Overwriting
            next(reader)
        for record in reader:
            yield transform(record, url, fieldnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

[StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) supports seeking.

```
csv_file = io.StringIO(io.TextIOWrapper(csv_binary, "utf-8").read())
has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csv_file.read(1024))
csv_file.seek(0)
```

Comment: That does work, thanks. Does the `read()` call mean that it loads the entire file into the `StringIO` object, or is it iterating over the file as I pull from the `csv_file`?

Comment: Yeah, the read call pretty much means that the file is read into memory. If that's an issue (I can't really imagine) then a better solution (like concatenating two streams - one the 1024 bytes "pee'k" one and the other the rest) might do the trick.